# How to pass commands through ssh to dd-wrt with a loop using a variable from a text file?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, busybox, dd-wrt

So far I have been able to create a small script using ssh combined with expect to pass a single command through to the dd-wrt router that I am working with. Now that this has been accomplished I wish to pass the same command several times through the ssh log-in instead of just one from a text file, if it is possible.

The other way to accomplish this would be to create a loop and pass the command over, and over again. I would have to use a variable though because the data for the command in the text file changes.

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/expect -f
```

set password **password**

```
    spawn ssh -l root x.x.x.x -p "command"
    expect "*password:*"
    send -- "$password\r"
    send -- "\r"
```

From what I can see creating a loop would be the easiest way, but I may be wrong. **NOTE** that the "command & variables" that I want to pass through are in a **separate text file**, and that it needs to read/take each line and insert each one into the loop. Unless there is a way to send them through all at once.

```
#!/bin/expect -f
```

set password **password**

```
    spawn ssh -l root x.x.x.x -p "command Variable" <-- Command to be passed through
    expect "*password:*"
    send -- "$password\r"
    send -- "\r"
```

It is the same command every time in the text file, only the variable changes.

test.txt

```
command xxxxxxx
command xxxxxxx
command xxxxxxx
command xxxxxxx
```

Thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
 password="your_password"
 cat test.txt|while read line
 do
   for i in $line
     do
       ssh.exp $i $password
     done
 done
```

ssh.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set command [lrange $argv 0 0] 
set password [lrange $argv 1 1] 
spawn ssh -l root x.x.x.x -p "$command"
expect "*password:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
```

And test.txt with list of your commands. Each on the different line.

Comment: The loop works excellent thank-you, However I have removed the command from the text file, and put it in front of "$command" since it was only carrying the variable over to the ssh.exp file.